# Cmake project with multiple directories and multiple CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been given some C++ source files, together with a CMakeLists.txt file, which compile to create an executable. I now want to add my own source files to this project. However, I want to keep the original source files, and the original CMakeLists file, separate from the new files.

So, I want my solution to look like this:

```
/Project
/Project/src
/Project/src/CMakeLists.txt
/Project/src/OriginalSource
/Project/src/OriginalSource/CMakeLists.txt
/Project/src/OriginalSource/Original.cpp
/Project/src/NewSource
/Project/src/NewSource/CMakeLists.txt
/Project/src/NewSource/New.cpp
/Project/build
```

I want all the source files to then compile into an executable to be placed in the build directory. So my question is, what do I put in the three CMakeLists files, such that `src/OriginalSource/CMakeLists.txt` just compiles the original sources, `src/NewSource/CMakeLists.txt` just compiles the new sources, and `src/CMakeLists.txt` links together all these built sources, and creates an executable?

Comment: Don't you have a CMakeLists.txt at the Project level?

Comment: No, but I could add one (in fact I just have)!

Comment: @dresherjm: You should make that an answer ;). It is also what I use: One CMakeLists.txt and collect source-files from multiple subdirs.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a convenience library out of your code and then link it to the code you've already got. The idea is explained [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-March/003693.html).

Please see this link for more details:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No way to change the executable project in `OriginSource` without modifying the `CMakeLists.txt` in it. If you really do not want to modify the original project, you could write a new `CMakeLists.txt` including old and new sources.

One trick is define new sources in `/Project/src/CMakeLists.txt`, then include them in `/Project/src/OriginalSource/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(NEW_INCS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/NewSource)
file(GLOB NEW_SRCS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/NewSource/*.cpp)
```